# `Cannot drop table "globalLinks" because other objects depend on it` despite no models or objects depending on it. Sequelize and Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, database-migration

This error is preventing me from running `sequelize db:migrate:undo:all`.

The `globalLinks` table is a table I created in my second migration.

There are associations for this table created in a third migration.

There are no associations in any of the remaining models.

Are the `objects` mentioned in this error log referring to columns? tables? cells?
I know `db:migrate:undo:all` would undo each migration in reverse order starting from the most recent, so what would remain by the time I try to drop this table?

If it is any clue, I am undoing all of these migrations because the same table is giving me an issue when I try to add a column - I get the error: `ERROR: column "userId" of relation "globalLinks" already exists`

What's up with this table?

Comment: Look at the hints you get along with the error message. If your code helpfully hides the hints from you, run the `DROP TABLE` in `psql`.

Comment: "Are the objects mentioned in this error log referring to columns?"  What error log?

Comment: I cannot tell if it is referring to columns or tables.  There are no other "hints" that the error message provides, sadly.